# ¿Cuánto tiempo tarda AdMob en poner anunciós reales? Flutter

Tags: flutter, admob

### AdMob en Flutter

Hola, recientemente he creado una cuenta de **AdMob** (ya ha sido verificada), y he probado la publicidad en mi dipositivo con Android, primero lo intenté con **"Test Ad"** y posteriormente ingrese las credenciales necesarias para mostrar los anuncios reales (los cuales **ya aparecen pero solo en mi dipositivo,** ya que lo tengo agregado como dispotivo de pruebas).

**Saben de alguna configuración, tiempo de espera** que tenga que hacer para que en otros dispositivos les muestre los anuncios reales (la app no ha sido subida a PlayStore, pero si muestra los anuncios reales en mi dispositivo de prueba). 
O tal vez debo de quitar el id de dispositivo de cuenta del código?

```
const String testDevice = 'EL id de mi dispositivo';


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  static const MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    testDevices: testDevice != null ? <String>[testDevice] : null,
    nonPersonalizedAds: true,
    keywords: <String>['Game','F'],
    gender: MobileAdGender.unknown
  );//fragmento de código

   InterstitialAd _createInterAd(){
        return InterstitialAd(
          adUnitId: 'mi id de AdMob',
          targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
          listener: (MobileAdEvent event){
            print('InterAd $event');
          }
        );
    }//fragmento de código

  @override
  void initState() { 
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId:'app Id, AdMob');
    super.initState();
  }

_createInterAd()..load()..show();//Llamar al InterrstitialAd
```

Les muestro fragmentos de código para el funcionamiento de los anunucios

Answer (score 0):

si te aparecen los anuncios en modo test con el id de prueba entonces esta bien configurado , para que te aparezcan anuncios reales en todos los dispositivos tu aplicación tiene que estar en google play o en appstore ,elimina el testDevice y pon los id de producción. Ademas en las configuraciones de admob tiene que estar ok la cuenta en donde se realizara el deposito de las ganancias de la publicidad si no esta configurado esa parte no aparecerá la publicidad en producción.

Comment: Okay, muchas gracias edmacalopú

Answer (score 0):

**Si tienes una cuenta verificada y creaste un anuncio definido por un `admob_app_id` no hay tiempo definido, debes esperar un poco para que los servidores de Google puedan entregar el anuncio.**

Asegura que en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` se encuentre definido el `appId` :

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="appId"/>
```

Elimina la definicion de dispositivo de prueba:

```
testDevices: <String>[]
```

Recuerda que es muy importante que si definiste la peticiòn del anuncio como InterstitialAd asegura que asì se encuentre configurado, ya que si no es asì esto puede causar la falla.

Comment: Okay, eliminé del "targeDevices" de "MobileAdTargetingInfo" y lo deje en la función InterstitialAd, el targetInfo. Gracias!!!.